# Leaflet JS, add search box by cities

Tags: arcgis-server, leaflet, javascript

I have developed an application using `leaflet JS`, which loads the services from the ArcGIS server via REST API.

I want to put a search box to search by cities. Should I load a base map to be able to search? How should I configure the search box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [leaflet-control-geocoder](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder) in order to do that, all you have to do is include it in your JS code.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);
```

Comment: Should I load the base map for that?

Comment: No, you only need a leaflet map

Comment: Does it work as Lat/long search?

Comment: @Leeloo yes it does support reverse geocoding by using the method `reverse(<L.LatLng> location, <Number> scale, callback, context)`

Comment: Thank you. Could you show an example of usage?